# Remove underline in hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I need to get rid of an underline in a hyperlink.

```
<div id='something'>
   <h2>
      <a href='http://somerandomurl'>Photo</a>
   </h2>
</div>
```

I'm using this CSS, but it won't work.

```css
#something h2 a{text-decoration:none}
```

Comment: with that `#something` fix it still doesnt work for you?

Comment: @RGB correct. I made a mistake in the question, in id = x and #x those were the same variable in my application

Answer (score 5):

Here is the css you want:

```
#something a:link {text-decoration:none;}
#something a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
#something a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
#something a:active {text-decoration:underline;}
```

The specific CSS you want to target depends on what exactly you are looking for.  For example, if you want all links in 'something' to not be underlined, do what I wrote above.  But if you wanted all links to not be underlined, you would not put the #something, etc.  Read about context selectors if your not sure what I mean.  Here is good link.

http://www.daaq.net/old/css/index.php?page=css+context+selectors&parent=css+syntax

Hope that helps

Comment: but i need to specify that it is the one in the id="something"

Comment: Ive added it so it specifically targets the a tags in 'something'.  You can get more specific and add #something h2 a {...} if you want only the h2 links to have no underline, and all the other links in 'something' to still be underlined.

Answer (score 1):

```css
a:link, a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

what is `#ugc`?

you need...

```
#something h2 a { text-decoration: none; }
```

you can also define

`a:hover, a:link, a:visited`

...if needed for different states

Comment: @Kevin, then spread the love and accept it as the correct answer, pls! :) http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1):

The style you have should work, except the `id` in your selector is wrong..it should be

```
#something h2 a{text-decoration:none}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V4e8m/2/